# select2 with jsonform don't work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, jquery-select2

I'm trying to render Multiple select2 with json form but I can't

```
$('#resource-form').jsonForm({
  schema: {
    rest: {
      type: 'object',
        properties: {
          template_id: {
            type: "array",
            items: {
              type: "string",
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  form: [
    {
      type: "select",
      key: "rest.template_id[]"
    }
  ]
}

$("select[name='rest.template_id[]']").select2({
  data: data,
  multiple: true
})
```

Select2 work very fine but if i submit form that backend get empty template_id param

```
{"rest"=>{"template_id"=>[]}}
```

I think I created incorrect schema and form. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack that will work for you. This will get all of the select field and turn it to select2.

```
$("select").select2({
  data: data,
  multiple: true
})
```

But if you want something specific, look for the Select field id that jsonform profide and pass it on as so.

```
$("@root_something").select2({
  data: data,
  multiple: true
})
```